# Python: Efficiency when reading a file without a default delimiter with millions of records and placing it in a dataframe (pandas)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

**Python: What would be the most efficient way to read a file without a default delimiter with millions of records and place it in a "data frame (pandas)"?**

The File is : **"file_sd.txt"**

```
 A123456MESTUDIANTE 000-12
 A123457MPROFESOR   003103
 I128734MPROGRAMADOR00-111
 A129863FARQUITECTO 00-456
```

```
# Fields and position:
# - Activity Indicator :  indAct     -> 01 Character
# - Person Code        :  codPer     -> 06 Characters
# - Gender (M / F)     :  sex        -> 01 Character
# - Occupation         :  occupation -> 11 Characters
# - Amount(User format):  amount     -> 06 Characters (Convert to Number)
```

I'm not sure. Is this the best option?:

```
 import pandas as pd 
 import numpy as np

 def stoI(cad):
     pos =  cad.find("-")
     if pos < 0: return int(cad)  
     return int(cad[pos+1:])*-1 

 #Read Txt
 data = pd.read_csv(r'D:\file_sd.txt',header = None)
 data_sep = pd.DataFrame(
     {
         'indAct'   :data[0].str.slice(0,1),
         'codPer'   :data[0].str.slice(1,7),
         'sexo'     :data[0].str.slice(7,8),
         'ocupac'   :data[0].str.slice(8,19),
         'monto'    :np.vectorize(stoI)(data[0].str.slice(19,25))
     })
```

```
 print(data_sep)

   indAct  codPer sexo       ocupac  monto
 0      A  123456    M  ESTUDIANTE     -12
 1      A  123457    M  PROFESOR      3103
 2      I  128734    M  PROGRAMADOR   -111
 3      A  129863    F  ARQUITECTO    -456
```

**This solution for 7 million rows.the result is: **

```
%timeit df_slice()
11.1 s ± 166 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a fixed-width file, so you should use the appropriate [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) reader. In this case we will specify the number of characters that belong to each field and the column names.

```
df = pd.read_fwf('test.txt', header=None, widths=[1, 6, 1, 11, 6])
df.columns = ['indAct' ,'codPer', 'sexo', 'ocupac', 'monto']
#  indAct  codPer sexo       ocupac   monto
#0      A  123456    M   ESTUDIANTE  000-12
#1      A  123457    M     PROFESOR  003103
#2      I  128734    M  PROGRAMADOR  00-111
#3      A  129863    F   ARQUITECTO  00-456
```

Now you can fix the dtypes of fields. `'monto'` can be made into a number by stripping the 0s and calling `pd.to_numeric`.

```
df['monto'] = pd.to_numeric(df['monto'].str.strip('0'), errors='coerce')
#  indAct  codPer sexo       ocupac  monto
#0      A  123456    M   ESTUDIANTE    -12
#1      A  123457    M     PROFESOR   3103
#2      I  128734    M  PROGRAMADOR   -111
#3      A  129863    F   ARQUITECTO   -456
```

---

As your comment notes this might on the surface *seem* slower. The advantage is that `pd.read_fwf`, as an I/O operation has a lot of automatic data cleaning.

- It will properly downcast columns from object if all data are int/float/numeric. For string slicing, you need to manually typecast the columns.
- It will properly trim the whitespace from strings in fields that don't fully consume the character limit. This is an additional step you need to perform after slicing.
- It properly fills missing data (all blank fields) with `NaN`. string slicing will keep the blank strings and must be dealt with separately. `pandas` does not recognize `''` as null, so this is how missing data should be properly handled.

In the case of many object columns that all fully encompass the entire character limit, with no missing data, string slicing has the advantage. But for a general unknown dataset, that you need to ingest and ETL,  once start tacking on string stripping and type conversions to every column, you will likely find that the designated `pandas` I/O operations are the best option.

Comment: This solution is slower when there are more rows (Millions of rows). For example, 7 million rows. the result is:

`%timeit df_slice() 
10.2 s ± 498 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`


`def df_fwf():
    df = pd.read_fwf(r'D:\file_sin_delimitadores.txt', header=None, widths=[1, 6, 1, 11, 6])
    df.columns = ['indAct' ,'codPer', 'sexo', 'ocupac', 'monto']
    df['monto'] = pd.to_numeric(df['monto'].str.strip('0'), errors='coerce')
    return df`


`%timeit df_fwf()
35 s ± 2.9 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: @VictorCervantes please see the update. `pd.read_fwf` is doing a lot of other data cleaning and type conversions as it is an I/O operation. If you plan to do any kind of analyses, these operations are likely going to be required upstream anyway (conversion to numeric, stripping whitespace from strings, representing missing data as `NaN`). So while you may have succeeded in getting a slightly faster way to split the data into columns, you've mostly just off-loaded a lot of the data cleaning to another step.

Answer (score 0):

You can [extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the columns using regex pattern matching. For the data in question, we can define the regex as:

```
data[0].str.extract('(?P<indAct>[AI]{1})(?P<codPer>[0-9]{6})(?P<sexo>[MF]{1})(?P<ocupac>[A-Z\s]{11})[0]*[^-|1-9](?P<monto>[0-9-\s]*$)')
```

The assumption is that the data is clean, which may or may not be a valid assumption.

Here is a comparison of the approach in the question and the one here:

```
#Data size is 300 rows. ( 4 rows in the question replicated 75 times)



import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

 #Returns a number from a string with zeros to the left, For example: stoI('0000-810') return -810
def stoI(cad):
    pos =  cad.find("-")
    if pos < 0: return int(cad)  
    return int(cad[pos+1:])*-1 

data = pd.read_csv('file_sd.txt',header = None)

#Read Txt
def df_slice(): 
    return pd.DataFrame(
     {
         'indAct'   :data[0].str.slice(0,1),
         'codPer'   :data[0].str.slice(1,7),
         'sexo'     :data[0].str.slice(7,8),
         'ocupac'   :data[0].str.slice(8,19),
         'monto'    :np.vectorize(stoI)(data[0].str.slice(19,25))
     })

def df_extract():
    return data[0].str.extract('(?P<indAct>[AI]{1})(?P<codPer>[0-9]{6})(?P<sexo>[MF]{1})(?P<ocupac>[A-Z\s]{11})[0]*[^-|1-9](?P<monto>[0-9-\s]*$)')


%timeit df_slice()
1.84 ms ± 30.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


%timeit df_extract()
975 µs ± 15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution is slower when there are more rows (Millions of rows).
For example, 7 million rows.

the result is: 

`%timeit df_slice() 
10.2 s ± 498 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`


`%timeit  df_extract()
12.5 s ± 1.07 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: @VictorCervantes great ! I think the method which you are using is the most efficient for your data.